# MVC: Property change events for nested models

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm building a GUI application and try to adhere to the MVC principle as good as I can.

Therefore my model fires `PropertyChangeEvent`s with the help of `PropertyChangeSupport` so the GUI knows what to update when.

The model of my application is nested, i.e. I have a main model class that contains some properties or `List`s of other model classes which in turn might contain more model classes.

A simple example:

```
public class MainModel {
    private int someData;
    private List<Stuff> stuffList;
    // imagine PropertyChangeSupport and appropriate getters/setters
    // for both MainModel and Stuff
}
```

Now both `MainModel` and `Stuff` have `PropertyChangeSupport`. If someone listens to events fired from `MainModel`, it gets changes of `someData` and from adding/deleting to/from the list `stuffList`.

But what if someone wants to get events from changes made to the individual elements of `stuffList`? There are two possibilities:

1. The observer has to fetch the list of `Stuff` elements and register as a listener to each element separately.
2. The main model registers itself as a listener to the elements of `stuffList` when they are added and forwards these events to the listener of the main model.

This is how it looks like with the first approach:

```
mainModelInstance.addListener("new stuff element", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        Stuff s = (Stuff) evt.getNewValue();
        s.addListener( // ... and so on
        );
    }
});
```

I think 1. has the advantage of keeping the model clean and dumb but leads to code duplication (many UI elements have to listen to changes to `stuffList` and add themselves dynamically to the new `Stuff` elements, see above). With 2. its the opposite: The client code is not as messy but the model acts partly as a listener which somehow doesn't *feel right*. That's why I currently use the first approach.

What are your thoughts? Maybe I'm too harsh on myself and 2. is okay. Or maybe there is a completely different (and better) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For at least 20 years, I've programmed MVC models observing other models (like for doing what is now called MVP[resenter] or MVVM patterns), and here are some heuristics I'd offer...

(1) Views and Controllers are hierarchical, and GUI event handling has long recognized that by letting event listeners listen at different levels of the hierarchy (like directly at a button level, or at the entire web page level). Each event specifies the most specific component associated with the event even if a higher level container was being listened to (aka observed). Events are said to "bubble up".

(2) Models can equally be hierarchical. The Model-generated "update" event can also use the same technique as above, specifying in the event the most specific "inner model" associated with the update event, but allowing observing at the "outer" composite model level. Observer update events can "bubble up".

(3) There is a common paradigm for hierarchical models...the spreadsheet. Each cell is a model that observes the other models/cells referenced in its formula.

Comment: After over four months finally an answer! Thanks a bunch. In the meantime I changed teams and got rid of that nasty GUI programming but your answer is insightful for me nonetheless.